# Overrinding a field in different table on django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want when i save new order, to save the order.id_order on company.last_order

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    last_order = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)

class Order(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_order = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the ***`save(...)`*** method of the **`Order`** class

```
class Order(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_order = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        created = not self.pk
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if created:
            Company.objects \
                .filter(pk=self.company_id) \
                .update(last_order=self.id_order)
```

Comment: good job, pls, any idea to have a unique id_order for each company ? company A with id orders for ex 1, 2, 3 ... but cannot have order 3 two times. company B with id orders for ex 10, 20, 30 ... but cannot have order 30 two times. or in another way, if this company.id_order already exists, cannot save it again

Comment: It seems like you are searching for [**`unique=True`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique). If not, better you ask a separate question.